# cursor becomes not-allowed and browser stops reading mouse event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following code, i made a simple slider with two slider button in it to read range and minimum value.

and I have set the minimum value of slider so that user cannot decrease the range beyond a minimum limit.

slider works somewhat correct! but when a user reaches the minimum range limit, and the user cannot decrease the range further but the user should be allowed to increase the range.

but after the minimum range is hit and when user tries to increase the range the cursor goes `not-allowed` like and browser stops reading any kind of mouse event at that time, and after that, every time user tries to increase the range this happens and the user no longer can increase the range.

And sometimes this happens without any reason?

play with it for some time to get the issue?

why does the cursor go `not-allowed` type when the user tries to increase the range after the minimum range is hit?

code: https://jsfiddle.net/nyfv1ahe/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0,
    b = 0,
    timeoutId;
  $("#button1").mousedown(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    $(".slider").mousemove(function(event) {
      a = event.clientX - 25;
      if (($(".slider").width() - a - b) >= 130) {
        $(".slider").css("padding-left", a);
      }
    });
  });
  $("#button1").mouseup(function() {
    $(".slider").unbind("mousemove");
  });
  $("#button1").mouseout(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      $(".slider").unbind("mousemove");
    }, 500);
  });
  $("#button2").mousedown(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    $(".slider").mousemove(function(event) {
      b = $(".slider").width() - event.clientX - 25;
      if (($(".slider").width() - a - b) >= 130) {
        $(".slider").css("padding-right", b);
      }
    });
  });
  $("#button2").mouseup(function() {
    $(".slider").unbind("mousemove");
  });
  $("#button2").mouseout(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      $(".slider").unbind("mousemove");
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}

#button1 {
  left: 25px;
}

#button2 {
  right: 50px;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 -30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="button" id="button1"></div>
    <div class="range"></div>
    <div class="button" id="button2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

if you remove `mouseout` event from both the button then it works somewhat correct but the problem with this is that sometimes button stick to the user mouse even after the user has clicked out of the button!

Comment: I can't drag the right slider

Comment: initially, you can slide the both slider button! refresh the page and see!

Comment: [Are you sure??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yhhV.gif)

Comment: try fiddle! but initially, it is working..!!

Comment: same in fiddle too

Comment: in my pc it is working, how did you share that gif? and also try full screen! if none of them works the remove moveout event from the code from both the button!  but that also shows the problem mouse goes not-allowed and mouse event stops working.

Comment: try browsing with chrome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151097/discussion-between-rahul-and-sagar-v).

Comment: hi @rahul, have you found a solution for this? as i have the same problem currently in chrome.

Comment: no! but it is not the way to do, i think you can use animation.

Answer (score 1):

https://javascript.info/mouse-drag-and-drop

```
   ball.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
   };
```

And then everything will be fine))

Answer (score 1):

ADLADS (A Day Late, A Dollar Short)
From [JQUERY How to disable not-allowed cursor while dragging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534302/),
(user 'Remembered to Post Solution'), add

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to your mousemove function.